# Bracket usage in CSS

Tags: css, brackets

Can someone help me understand the usage of brackets in this instance? I'm used to seeing class names in css like .mobilecontent {}. I'm trying to understand how this is different?

```
    <style>@media screen and (max-width:480px) {   
                div[class=mobilecontent]{
                display: block !important;
                max-height: none !important;
                }
            }</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the square brackets `[...]`*, that's an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). It can be used with `class` or with any other HTML attribute.

The difference here is that it matches only elements with that exact value for the attribute (`class="mobilecontent"`). It won't, for example, match an element with `class="mobilecontent some-other-class"`. The `.mobilecontent` selector, meanwhile, would match both of these.

---

*In American English, "brackets" with no qualifier usually refers to these, but in British English, it refers to parentheses `(...)` instead.

Comment: Thank you - that's very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The `[attribute=value]` selector is used to select elements with the specified attribute and value. Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp

It could be use in different situations, for example if you want to remove the text-decoration from links if there's a class.

```
a[class] {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

The example on your question is going to apply the styles when the screen has an equal or less `max-width` of 480px and a class named `mobilecontent`.